# The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, deb, debian-stretch

I have an error when I am building my Docker containers. It seems that there are problems with Postgres Stretch for Debian. I saw that Debian strech was removed and no longer supported.

I found similar problem here: [The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74401375/the-repository-http-apt-postgresql-org-pub-repos-apt-stretch-pgdg-release-do/74468135#74468135) but i didn't managed to solve my problem.

Here is an error:

```
W: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/stretch-pgdg/11/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install dos2unix &&     apt-get clean' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

And here's part of my Dockerfile that I'm trying to run:

```
FROM debian:jessie
MAINTAINER Open Knowledge

# Install required system packages
RUN apt-get -q -y update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -q -y upgrade \
    && apt-get -q -y install \
          curl \
        python-dev \
        python-pip \
        python-virtualenv \
        python-wheel \
        libpq-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libgeos-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libgeos-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        postgresql-client \
        build-essential \
        git-core \
        vim \
        wget \
    && apt-get -q clean \
    && apt-get install -y dos2unix
```

Do you maybe know what I should add or remove in my Dockerfile file to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74401375/the-repository-http-apt-postgresql-org-pub-repos-apt-stretch-pgdg-release-do

Comment: Unfortunaltey I can not opent this and seems that the questions is deleted.

Answer (score 6):

Debian stretch [is no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Y2kmqL%2BpCuSZiQBV%40msg.df7cb.de)

You could use this deb package instead:

`deb https://apt-archive.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg main`

Comment: Unfortunaltey this didn't solved my problem.
I still have some errors-->

failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get -q -y update     && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -q -y upgrade     && apt-get -q -y install         python-dev         python-pip         python-virtualenv         python-wheel         libpq-dev         libxml2-dev         libxslt-dev       libgeos-dev     libssl-dev         libffi-dev       postgresql-client         build-essential         git-core         vim         wget     && apt-get -q clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100

Comment: HERE MY DOCKERFILE --> FROM mdillon/postgis
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install dos2unix && \
    apt-get clean
# Allow connections; we don't map out any ports so only linked docker containers can connect
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf

ENV POSTGRES_DB test
ENV POSTGRES_USER test
ARG POSTGRES_PASSWORD
ARG DS_RO_PASS

# Include datastore setup cripts
COPY ./postgresql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN dos2unix /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00_create_datastore.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix